# can I use JS to add a unix timestamp to <img> end of the src?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need add the random int or unix timestamp to all `img src=""` whit `class='avatar'`

```html
<img src="a.png" alt="" class="avatar">
<img src="b.png" alt="" class="avatar">
<img src="c.png" alt="" class="avatar">
```

I know I can use php to set it
`<img src="a.png?<?php echo time();?>" alt="" class="avatar">`

But I want to try Js to do that.

my code for try, but not work

```js
<script>
var now = Date.now()
var img_src = document.querySelector(".avatar").src;
document.querySelector(".avatar").src = img_src+"?"+now;).
</script>
```

why add a random int or unix timestamp to the end of img src?

Because I using a CDN

when the user update some photos can't see the new photo on real time.

1. I prefer use JS don  use server side.
2. the file name is fixed forever, can't change.

any other suggest?

Comment: Breaking caching of the images on every page load rather defeats much of the benefit of using a CDN in the first place. Better to solve this with a build toolchain that generates unique filenames based on, for example, an MD5 signature.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. But in our case, we can not use unique filenames. And we just do some imges class not all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the images with the querySelectorAll method on the document object.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".avatar");
```

After that you can change the src attribute for each of them.

```
images.forEach((image) => {
  image.src = image.src + "?random=" + Date.now();
});
```

Comment: NB: this will cause every image tag to first try the URL without the timestamp added, slowing down the site and filling the server log with extra requests.